# Best object relation mapping framework to use with .net and mono?

Tags: .net, orm, mono

I'm doing some research for my end of degree project: a multiplattform application developed using .net3.5 and mono2.0

I need some opinion about what you people think is the best Object Relational Mapping framework which will also run with mono.

Additionaly, any opinion about what ORM will work the best for my project, will be handy (think in simplicity :) )

My project will be a desktop application, with a simply DB that will be using SQL-Lite as there is no need for multiple connections nor multiuser access. Intended development platforms are Mac & Win (no linux by the moment, but i asume that if I manage to make it work with mac, adding support for linux in the future will be relative easy :) )

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate is by far the best choice 
there are also very good tools out there, I recommend: 
[NHibernate Analyzer](http://ayende.com/projects/nhibernate-query-analyzer.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I would skip NHibernate and use Castle ActiveRecord, it's a layer ontop of NHibernate and I find it significantly easier to work with.  I use it for development on Mono and have had no problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate.

It will also be usefull when you decide to switch to Java.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first option (without the MS offerings) would have to be [NHibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/343.html). I *think* it plays nicely on mono...

Answer (score 0):

[ECO](http://www.capableobjects.com) is a very capable framework. Free to use up to 12 classes.